# Rename [status-bydesign] to [status-by-design]

Tags: feature-request, tags

Since "by design" is two words, the current name violates the current tag naming scheme and is thus counterintuitive.

The specific case that pushed me to propose this is misnaming the tag when writing its name from the top of my head at [Navigating back after doing AJAX changes produces a stale cached version of the page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300148/navigating-back-after-doing-ajax-changes-produces-a-stale-cached-version-of-the#comment976031_300148).

Comment: I believe they decided to use "bydesign" to formalize the status tag format: [status-oneworddescription]. The same thing also happens on [tag:status-norepro].

Comment: I too believe so, but that doesn't negate the fact that it's contrary to the general tag naming scheme and thus counterintuitive.

Comment: If that's the case, then include the other one to be changed to [status-no-repro]?

Comment: I'd argue that "norepro" is one word (a jargon one). For two, it shall be "not-reproducible" or "cant-reproduce". So, better leave it out of this specific question so as not to introduce any side issues.

Comment: @Elias I partially agree, but "norepro" is only an abbreviation, while "by design" is not. Maybe the real source of its current form is some variable name in the SE sources. :-)